# Modify View from a different thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, progressdialog

Am geting a JSON from server that is the content of my ListView.
Everything is fine, but I want to create a ProgressDialog while the Json is getin called.
The problem is that I need to call the JSON (with an http method) in a different thread and show the results in a ListView to the user.

Here is what am doing, but am getin the error `"05-09 12:13:28.358: W/System.err(344): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."`

```
try {       
            final ProgressDialog progDailog;
            progDailog =ProgressDialog.show(this,"HI", "Loading");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(executeHttpGet("http://m-devsnbp.insightlabs.cl/cuentos/json"));
                        progDailog.cancel();
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> talesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        talesList = jsonToHash(json);
                        adapter = new LazyAdapter((Activity) ctx, talesList, 2);    
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I update my views from a different thread? Or is it a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update ui on the main ui thread. Use runOnUiThread

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 
                    progDailog.cancel(); 
                    adapter = new LazyAdapter((Activity) ctx, talesList, 2);    
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);   
                  }
                 });
```

Also consider using a asynctask. I would suggest ypu to use asynctask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
        ProgressDialog pd; 
        LazyAdapter adapter;  
        ListView list; 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> talesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

In your activity onCreate()

```
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
        pd.setTitle("Processing..."); 
        new TheTask().execute();
```

Define your AsyncTask as inner class in your activity class

```
    class extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();
      pd.show();
          
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 try 
                {
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(executeHttpGet("http://m-devsnbp.insightlabs.cl/cuentos/json"));
                    talesList = jsonToHash(json);
                    
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
    return null;
             
}
    
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            adapter = new LazyAdapter(AcctivityName.this, talesList, 2);    
            list.setAdapter(adapter); 
}  
    }
```

**Updated Jan 2021**

The above answer is outdated ( asynctask is derpecated). There are other new ways to update ui. Depedning on whether you use coroutines or rxjava you can update ui easily. Its better to ask a new question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to update your view from non-UI thread, you need to update it trough post() method:

```
try {       
            final ProgressDialog progDailog;
            progDailog =ProgressDialog.show(this,"HI", "Loading");

            Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(executeHttpGet("http://m-devsnbp.insightlabs.cl/cuentos/json"));
                        progDailog.cancel();
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> talesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        talesList = jsonToHash(json);
                        adapter = new LazyAdapter((Activity) ctx, talesList, 2);    
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
                }
            });

            post(mThread);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modyfing Views should be made only on UI Thread, so for me, You should try use a class that handles Activity reference and pass there runnable to run

```
class UIUpdater{
private static UIUpdater mInstance;
private Activity mActivity;
    public static UIUpdater getInstance()
    {
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new UIUpdater();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void runOnUiThread(Runnable run){
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(run);
    }
}
```

Another way is to use Loopers:
eg.

```
Looper mMainLooper = Looper.getMainLooper();
```

for more info see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better way to do this. Like using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

This is just a code sample for what you want to do.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> talesList;
  private LazyAdapter adapter;
  private Context mContext;

  public LongOperation(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    //operation start, show the dialog
    progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //connect to server and get json
    try 
    {
      JSONArray json = new JSONArray(executeHttpGet("http://m-devsnbp.insightlabs.cl/cuentos/json"));
      talesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      talesList = jsonToHash(json);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }      

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //operation end, dismiss the dialog and set result to list
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(mContext, talesList, 2);    
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

}
```

Some link you might wanna look at:

[AsyncTask Android Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

[Understanding AsyncTask](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)